# Integration of BitBucket and SonarQube on Pull Requests

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

What is the best way to trigger a SonarQube scan/analysis on a Pull Request, upon Pull Request creation in BitBucket?

Tech Stack:

BitBucket server v4.14.5 hosted on prem

SonarQube server 6.6 hosted on prem

Jenkins has been used to run the scans previously; would be easiest to continue down that path.

Mibex plugin not an option as it creates a new project and that workflow isn't acceptable to my architect.

Ideally, workflow would be:

Pull Request Workflow:

Developer creates pull request - pull request triggers SonarQube scan - scan posts results back to BitBucket.

Merge to Master Workflow:

On pull request merge to 'master' branch, another SonarQube scan is run against "master" to maintain baseline quality of code for 'master'

Comment: i see, we are doing circles :D - okay you found already the plugin which does a simple analysis - so this would be the way to go. If you do have some time, you could also wait for the release of sonarqube 6.7 LTS and the "development plugin"(commercial plugin) which allows branch support - but based on your recent questions, i think you already know the answers, what you can do - as you found both plugins which are doing the job. -> you should also mention in your question, why sonar-stash is not working for you!

Comment: I was directed to the "BitBucket Server Webhook to Jenkins" plugin... I configured it to run my Jenkins job on creation of pull request, passing along the pr_id; I determined that the plugin was not sending the PR ID when calling Jenkins and this was confirmed by plugin developer... as far as SonarStash by AmedeusIT as far as I can tell plays no part in this process. I am left with attempting to call the jenkins job with "Parameterized Builds for Jenkins"

Comment: just as a sidenote: we also tried those plugins, but in fact the best thing for us was https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.prnfs.pull-request-notifier-for-stash/server/overview -  it is not that intuitive to call a jenkins job, as you have to know the url, but if you do a simple GET-Call to https://<jenkinsserver>/job/<jobname>/buildWithParameters?... you can simple add the parameters as queryparams.

Comment: Simon, you've been a lifesaver for me during this process... I thank you for your help. You've been the only person answering my questions... I realize this comment is not in keeping w/community guidelines ("no 'thanks' comments") but I don't much care. You've helped a lot and I want to thank you for it. I'll check out the plugin and instructions you provide.

Comment: so I've set up the above referenced plugin. I invoke my job. I get the "WARNING: No valid crumb" issue from Jenkins, so that's fine, I know my job is getting called. I disable CSRF protection (internally hosted) and try again... the job doesn't run.. I see in my Jenkins logs the invocation of Spring singletons, etc., but Jenkins shows no job has been called. Any thoughts?

Comment: re: disregard the bit about the Spring stack calls proving anything in Jenkins.. thx.

Comment: I got it.... IT WORKS!!!!!

Comment: https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/ this should be helpful for you too, depending if this is an option